# How can you use git-svn to clone parts of an SVN repo, but still get all the branches

Tags: git-svn

Is there any way to use git-svn to clone only some folders of an SVN repo structure.  I'm trying to clone a repo that has some crazy big binary files and a number of subfolders that are just plain useless.  I've tried using the --ignore-paths option, but my clone seemed to just stall out doing nothing for an extremely long time.  Have any of you managed to make --ignore-paths work?  I can't find much on the webs where anyone else is running into this.  Maybe I'm the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most success I've had here is to manually create branches in git that mirror the SVN remote repository when necessary. The process has been the following:

1. Update .git/config file with:

> ```
>  [svn-remote "svn-branch-alias"]
>           url = http://svn/branches/crazybranchname/craziername/url/ 
>           fetch = :refs/remotes/git-branch-name
> ```

1. From the command line type: `git svn fetch 'svn-branch-alias'` to collect the SVN branch data into your local git repo.
2. Then type: `git checkout 'git-branch-name'` to go into a headless mode.
3. Finally type: `git checkout 'my-local-git-branch-name'` to create move head to the latest submission in that branch and create a local branch alias you can use.

You can now `commit` and `dcommit` as usual and still switch between various local git branches and your manually created SVN mirrors using the usual mechanisms.

Comment: I should say that this really just allows me to better manage a repo with an complex structure.  It doesn't do actually resolve the main issue which is providing a simple command to allow you to properly clone a complex SVN repo with git-svn.

Answer (score 1):

We've used the "ignore-paths" feature to ignore certain directories in a svn repo:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
        ignore-paths = ^(((branches|tags)/[^/]+|trunk)|)(huge/|mobile/)
```

This config ignores the "huge" and "mobile" subdirs of the repository in trunk, all branches and all tags.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can illustrate the structure of your Subversion repository to make it easier for us to suggest some solutions.

Are you trying to git svn clone the entire repository from the root-url? Have you tried cloning smaller parts of the repo, and then perhaps grafting several clones together?

Comment: The repository I've been trying to clone is similar to the OCAP RI open source project.  It's located on java.net.  Take a look if you'd like to see the structure they have.  It's pretty awful. My company has an internal copy of this repo with its own crazy structure that adds even more branches.

Comment: I've had some success by using --ignore-paths and only checking out one or 2 revisions from SVN.  But I'm still not really happy with it.  This might just be an intractable problem that isn't really worth solving.  

I was hoping I could git svn clone only a couple folders from all the branches.